# How can I programmatically find valid names for Mayavi colormaps?

Tags: python, scipy, mayavi

I have an application built on Mayavi where I let the user specify a colormap for some data. Because newer versions of Matplotlib have colormaps that Mayavi lacks, I'd like to be able to either use the native Mayavi colormap or make a lookuptable based on the Matplotlib colormap, if Mayavi doesn't offer it.

I could try and use the user-supplied name and catch the TraitError that is raised, but I'd rather just check the supplied name against an existing list of colors. For example, in Matplotlib I would do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def is_mpl_cmap(name):
    if name in dir(plt.cm):
        return True
    return False
```

Is there a similar repository of colormap names in Mayavi that I could access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from mayavi.core import lut_manager

def is_tvtk_cmap(name): return name in lut_manager.lut_mode_list()
```

Comment: If you do this a very large number of times, store the list as a variable because several list insertions are done whenever you call this function.  But it should still be pretty fast.